# Iterate over list of file names to see if file name is in dictionary Values (Valuse are lists), then print Key and file name

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm limited to using python 2.7 for this work.

I'd like to iterate over the `file_list` looking for which file names contain any of the dict values lists.
Then print the dict key and the file name.

```
## dictionary derived from opening and reading csv file
name_dict = {'kat': ['1', '2', '4'], 'rod': ['3', '7', '9'], 'tim': ['5', '6', '8']} 

## list of files in a directory
file_list = ['1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '4.pdf', '5.pdf', '6.pdf', '7.pdf', '8.pdf', '9.pdf']
```

This is for a project I volunteered for at work and I'm new-ish to python.
It is the dictionary `key:values` as a list that is really confusing me.

Any help is much appreciated:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_list = ['1.pdf', '2.pdf', '3.pdf', '4.pdf', '5.pdf', '6.pdf', '7.pdf', '8.pdf', '9.pdf']
name_dict = {'kat': ['1', '2', '4'], 'rod': ['3', '7', '9'], 'tim': ['5', '6', '8']}

for file in file_list:
    file_no_ext = '.'.join(file.split('.')[:-1])
    for key, value in name_dict.items():
        if file_no_ext in value:
            print(f'{file}: {key}')
            break
```

and output:

```
1.pdf: kat
2.pdf: kat
3.pdf: rod
4.pdf: kat
5.pdf: tim
6.pdf: tim
7.pdf: rod
8.pdf: tim
9.pdf: rod
```

Comment: Amin - thank you for your help and quick response, greatly appreciate your help - Kathy